# how can I reconstruct original data after using pca with svd in python?

Tags: python, pca, svd

I apply pca in my data set.
I use this code :

Ap1 is my data after calculating mean on it.
now I want to reconstruct my original data from this new component.
what work should I do?
thanks

```py
pca = PCA(n_components=3).fit(Ap1)
U = pca.components_          
S = pca.explained_variance_
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Do you want to apply PCA on the data? Or what do you want to "reconstruct"? You cannot reconstruct higher-dimensional data from their low-dimensional representation. If your data is already 3-dimensional, you could apply the inverse rotation. I don't see the sense in it though.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Hi,thanks for your comment. I apply PCA on my data. I implement another method on my data too. I want to use these component to reconstruct my data to check the accuracy....
I do this by another method too.